# rails, inverse_of の関連付け

Tags: ruby-on-rails

名前をつけて関連付けたいです。
Article.xxx には Post.id が入っています。
以下の設定で、includesなどしたときに、

`Could not find the inverse association for hoge_post (:articles in Post)`

とエラーが出ます。どこが間違っているのでしょうか？

> Post
>
> has_many :custom_articles, inverse_of: :hoge_post, class_name:
>   'Article', foreign_key: 'xxx'
>
> Article
>
> belongs_to :hoge_post, inverse_of: :articles, class_name: 'Post',
>   foreign_key: 'xxx'

Answer (score 3):

`inverse_of: :articles`と指定されていますが`articles`という関連付けが定義されていません。

`has_many :custom_articles`に合わせて`inverse_of: :custom_articles`とすればよいでしょう。(もしくは関連付けの方の名前を変える)